# Troubleshooting 403 Forbidden Error when Uploading PDFs via AJAX in a Spring Boot Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

I am facing an issue with uploading PDFs via AJAX in my Spring Boot application. Most PDFs are successfully uploaded, but for 1-2 specific PDFs, I encounter a 403 Forbidden error with the message `POST https://develop.abc.in/parseResume 403 (Forbidden).` The PDFs seem fine to me, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause of the problem. I have included the relevant code snippet for reference. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
        // ajax call for Individual add  candidate resume /
        function submitIndividualSharedFileInviteCandidate() {
            var data = new FormData();
            var files = $('#individual')[0].files
            data.append('file',files[0]);
            if (!validateIndividualResumeUpload()) {
                return false;
            }else{     
                if(dummyData == "DummyData"){
                    currentactivity_dummyData = "btn_shareEmployee_uploadIndResume";
                    deleteDummyData();
                    removeDummyData="removeDummyData";
                    }
              }     


            // var data = new FormData(formdata);
            var csrf = $("input[name='_csrf']").attr("value")

            $.ajax({
                headers : {
                    "X-CSRF-TOKEN" : csrf
                },
                enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
                processData : false, // Important!
                contentType : false,
                cache : false, //this is my servlet
                crossDomain: true, // Set this option
                data : data,
                type : "POST",
                url : "./parseResume",

                success : function(result) {
                    if (result.status == "Done") {
                        current_employee_id = result.data.employeeId;
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        // $('#candidatesBlock1').empty();

                        
                    }
                    $(".tab-slider--navresumedetails li:nth-child(2)").trigger('click')
                    $(".tab-slider--navresumedetails li:nth-child(1)").css('pointer-events', 'none');
                    // $(".add_candidate_form_parent").css('height', '698px');
                    $(".add_candidate_form_parent").css('overflow', 'auto');
                    
                    getSupplierEmail()
                    
                    var obj = result.data;
                    unparsed_resumes_list = obj;
                    current_employee_id = obj.employeeId;
                    $('#userId_unparesedResume').val(obj.employeeId);
                    unparsedBulkSharedResumePreview(obj);
                    $('#btn_save_unparsedSharedBulkResumes').html('Save');

                    
                    if (result.status == "error") {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        
                    }
                },
                error : function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
            }
```

[pdf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVMoK.png)

Comment: You need to debug the server not client. The server is returning `403` which means the server received the request but refused to fulfill it. Files might be bigger than the max upload set on server. also check the logs.

Comment: size of the file is in kb. I have checked it.

Comment: Debug the code that's  processing the upload in ./parseResume and check your httpd logs. Could be issues with pdf headers but definitely not a js issue.

Comment: It directly goes into error block and I am getting 403 error but when I repair the pdf or download it again after some changes then it works fine. Is there any chance that pdf is corrupted and if yes then how to identify where is the problem ?